# Json.NET: Deserializing nested dictionaries

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

When deserializing an object to a `Dictionary` (`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string,object>>(json)`) nested objects are deserialized to `JObject`s. Is it possible to force nested objects to be deserialized to `Dictionary`s?

Comment: This article provides an easy way to deserialize a nested JSON obejct into a Dictionary: https://buildplease.com/pages/json/

Comment: May not be Dictionary, but I myself have been deserializing to ExpandoObject to get the same effect.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I found a way to convert all nested objects to `Dictionary<string,object>` by providing a `CustomCreationConverter` implementation:

```
class MyConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    public override IDictionary<string, object> Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // in addition to handling IDictionary<string, object>
        // we want to handle the deserialization of dict value
        // which is of type object
        return objectType == typeof(object) || base.CanConvert(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject
            || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

        // if the next token is not an object
        // then fall back on standard deserializer (strings, numbers etc.)
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\test.json");
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(
            json, new JsonConverter[] {new MyConverter()});
    }
}
```

Documentation: **[CustomCreationConverter with Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomCreationConverter.htm)**

Answer (score 14):

I had a very similar but slightly more complex need when I ran across this Q. At first I thought maybe I could adapt the accepted answer, but that seemed a bit complicated and I ended up taking a different approach. I was attempting to put a modern JSON layer on top of a legacy C++ API. I'll spare you the details of that, and just say the requirements boil down to:

- JSON objects become `Dictionary<string,object>`.
- JSON arrays become `List<object>`.
- JSON values become the corresponding primitive CLR values.
- The objects and arrays can be infinitely nested.

I first deserialize the request string into a Newtonsoft JSON object and then call my method to convert in accordance with the above requirements:

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestString);
var apiRequest = ToApiRequest(jsonObject);
// call the legacy C++ API ...
```

Here is my method that converts to the structure the API expects:

```
    private static object ToApiRequest(object requestObject)
    {
        switch (requestObject)
        {
            case JObject jObject: // objects become Dictionary<string,object>
                return ((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>) jObject).ToDictionary(j => j.Key, j => ToApiRequest(j.Value));
            case JArray jArray: // arrays become List<object>
                return jArray.Select(ToApiRequest).ToList();
            case JValue jValue: // values just become the value
                return jValue.Value;
            default: // don't know what to do here
                throw new Exception($"Unsupported type: {requestObject.GetType()}");
        }
    }
```

I hope that someone can find this approach useful.

Comment: This was really useful. I was unable to decode this kind of response with the given solution.  {"id":2,"name":"root","descendants":[{"id":4,"name":"node2","descendants":[{"id":7,"name":"node21"},{"id":8,"name":"node22"}]},{"id":3,"name":"node1","descendants":[{"id":5,"name":"node11"},{"id":6,"name":"node12"}]}]}. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Alternative/Update:

I needed to deserialize a dictionary of dictionaries of `String`s and with current Json.NET (5.0) I did not had to create a CustomConverter, I just used (in VB.Net):

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IDictionary(Of String, IDictionary(Of String, String)))(jsonString)
```

Or, in C#:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<String, IDictionary<String, String>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: This does not support recursive/unknown json structures being converted properly.

Comment: This doesn't answer, as it specifically refers to a fixed levels of nesting

Answer (score 2):

[@AlexD's accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6417753/11425141) does not work ideally if there is an array in the json. It returns a `JArray` of `JObject` instead a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`

This can be solved by modifying the ReadJson() method:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

    //if it's an array serialize it as a list of dictionaries
    if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.ArrayStart)
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(List<Dictionary<string, object>>));    


    // if the next token is not an object
    // then fall back on standard deserializer (strings, numbers etc.)
    return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a nested/deep structure of "unknown" dictionaries that is serialized/deserialized to/from C# objects and JSON string. .NET 5.

If I use `Newtonsoft` it does not work automatically.

If I use `System.Text.Json` it works automatically.

```
//does NOT work (newtonDeserialized does not have the same data in the nested Dictionaries as in object):
var newtonSerialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
var newtonDeserialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WaitlistResponse>(newtonSerialized);

//Works (netDeserialized have the same data in the nested Directories as in object):
var netSerialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(object);
var netDeserialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WaitlistResponse>(netSerialized);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, not everything is nested dictionary. I also have an array that is key-value of primitive types and it throws exception when the object of the array is not a dictionary.

So, based on Phillip S' answer, I came up with

```cs
public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

            //if it's an array serialize it as a list of dictionaries
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(List<object>)); // instead of List<Dictionary<string, object>>
            }

            // if the next token is not an object
            // then fall back on standard deserializer (strings, numbers etc.)
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

Hope it helps those haven't got it working yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to serialize your dictionary values.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling= TypeNameHandling.All };

var serializeValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nestedDictionaryValues, settings);

//After serialize using deserialize using the same TypeNameHandling.

var deserializeValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializeValues, settings);
```