# how to convert NameValueCollection to JSON string?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, json, namevaluecollection

I tried:

```
  NameValueCollection Data = new NameValueCollection();
  Data.Add("foo","baa");
  string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Data);
```

it returns: `["foo"]` I expected `{"foo" : "baa"}` 
How do I to do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`NameValueCollection` isn't an IDictionary, so the `JavaScriptSerializer` cannot serialize it as you expect directly. You'll need to first convert it into a dictionary, then serialize it.

**Update**: following questions regarding multiple values per key, the call to `nvc[key]` will simply return them separated by a comma, which may be ok. If not, one can always call `GetValues` and decide what to do with the values appropriately. Updated the code below to show one possible way.

```
public class StackOverflow_7003740
{
    static Dictionary<string, object> NvcToDictionary(NameValueCollection nvc, bool handleMultipleValuesPerKey)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            if (handleMultipleValuesPerKey)
            {
                string[] values = nvc.GetValues(key);
                if (values.Length == 1)
                {
                    result.Add(key, values[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add(key, values);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(key, nvc[key]);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        nvc.Add("foo", "bar");
        nvc.Add("multiple", "first");
        nvc.Add("multiple", "second");

        foreach (var handleMultipleValuesPerKey in new bool[] { false, true })
        {
            if (handleMultipleValuesPerKey)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Using special handling for multiple values per key");
            }
            var dict = NvcToDictionary(nvc, handleMultipleValuesPerKey);
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NameValueCollection` could have multiple values per key, this does not address that issue.

Comment: This method will likely cause exceptions! The reason why NameValueCollection exists (and .NET doesn't use a dictionary sometimes) is to allow for multiple values per key. A dictionary requires one and only one key per value.

Comment: The method won't throw an exception. If there are multiple keys, `nvc[key]` would just return them joined by a `,` character. But for completeness sake, I updated the answer to be more explicit about it.

Comment: If the query string has not been made into a NameValueCollection then this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428947/how-do-i-convert-a-querystring-to-a-json-string

Comment: DotNetFiddle: Multiple Keys on NameValueCollection https://dotnetfiddle.net/hnYwGn

Answer (score 61):

One way to serialize NameValueCollection is by first converting it to Dictionary and then serialize the Dictionary. To convert to dictionary:

```
thenvc.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => thenvc[k]);
```

If you need to do the conversion frequently, you can also create an extension method to NameValueCollection:

```
public static class NVCExtender
{
    public static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(
                                        this NameValueCollection source)
    {
        return source.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => source[k]);
    }
}
```

so you can do the conversion in one line like this:

```
NameValueCollection Data = new NameValueCollection();
Data.Add("Foo", "baa");

var dict = Data.ToDictionary();
```

Then you can serialize the dictionary:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
// you get {"Foo":"baa"}
```

But NameValueCollection can have multiple values for one key, for example:

```
NameValueCollection Data = new NameValueCollection();
Data.Add("Foo", "baa");
Data.Add("Foo", "again?");
```

If you serialize this you will get `{"Foo":"baa,again?"}`.

You can modify the converter to produce `IDictionary<string, string[]>` instead:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string[]> ToDictionary(
                                    this NameValueCollection source)
{
    return source.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => source.GetValues(k));
}
```

So you can get serialized value like this: `{"Foo":["baa","again?"]}`.

Answer (score 3):

If your dictionary is not intended to contain many entries, you can use the class:
`System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary`

Answer (score 3):

For completeness' sake, and because the question continues to get asked (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52722950/3744182)), *as long as you are using Json.NET or `DataContractJsonSerializer` (but not `JavaScriptSerializer`)*, you could use the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and wrap the `NameValueCollection` in an `IDictionary<string, string[]>` adapter, and serialize that using any serializer that fully supports serializing arbitrary dictionaries.

Once such adapter is as follows:

```
public class NameValueCollectionDictionaryAdapter<TNameValueCollection> : IDictionary<string, string[]>
    where TNameValueCollection : NameValueCollection, new()
{
    readonly TNameValueCollection collection;

    public NameValueCollectionDictionaryAdapter() : this(new TNameValueCollection()) { }

    public NameValueCollectionDictionaryAdapter(TNameValueCollection collection)
    {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    // Method instead of a property to guarantee that nobody tries to serialize it.
    public TNameValueCollection GetCollection() { return collection; }

    #region IDictionary<string,string[]> Members

    public void Add(string key, string[] value)
    {
        if (collection.GetValues(key) != null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Duplicate key " + key);
        if (value == null)
            collection.Add(key, null);
        else
            foreach (var str in value)
                collection.Add(key, str);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key) { return collection.GetValues(key) != null; }

    public ICollection<string> Keys { get { return collection.AllKeys; } }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        bool found = ContainsKey(key);
        if (found)
            collection.Remove(key);
        return found;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out string[] value)
    {
        return (value = collection.GetValues(key)) != null;
    }

    public ICollection<string[]> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollectionAdapter<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>, string[]>(this, p => p.Value);
        }
    }

    public string[] this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            var value = collection.GetValues(key);
            if (value == null)
                throw new KeyNotFoundException(key);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            Remove(key);
            Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<KeyValuePair<string,string[]>> Members

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, string[]> item) { Add(item.Key, item.Value); }

    public void Clear() { collection.Clear(); }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, string[]> item)
    {
        string[] value;
        if (!TryGetValue(item.Key, out value))
            return false;
        return EqualityComparer<string[]>.Default.Equals(item.Value, value); // Consistent with Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, string[]>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
            array[arrayIndex++] = item;
    }

    public int Count { get { return collection.Count; } }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, string[]> item)
    {
        if (Contains(item))
            return Remove(item.Key);
        return false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string[]>> Members

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (string key in collection)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>(key, collection.GetValues(key));
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    #endregion
}

public static class NameValueCollectionExtensions
{
    public static NameValueCollectionDictionaryAdapter<TNameValueCollection> ToDictionaryAdapter<TNameValueCollection>(this TNameValueCollection collection)
        where TNameValueCollection : NameValueCollection, new()
    {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return new NameValueCollectionDictionaryAdapter<TNameValueCollection>(collection);
    }
}

public class ReadOnlyCollectionAdapter<TIn, TOut> : CollectionAdapterBase<TIn, TOut, ICollection<TIn>>
{
    public ReadOnlyCollectionAdapter(ICollection<TIn> collection, Func<TIn, TOut> toOuter)
        : base(() => collection, toOuter)
    {
    }

    public override void Add(TOut item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public override void Clear() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }

    public override bool Remove(TOut item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public abstract class CollectionAdapterBase<TIn, TOut, TCollection> : ICollection<TOut> 
    where TCollection : ICollection<TIn>
{
    readonly Func<TCollection> getCollection;
    readonly Func<TIn, TOut> toOuter;

    public CollectionAdapterBase(Func<TCollection> getCollection, Func<TIn, TOut> toOuter)
    {
        if (getCollection == null || toOuter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.getCollection = getCollection;
        this.toOuter = toOuter;
    }

    protected TCollection Collection { get { return getCollection(); } }

    protected TOut ToOuter(TIn inner) { return toOuter(inner); }

    #region ICollection<TOut> Members

    public abstract void Add(TOut item);

    public abstract void Clear();

    public virtual bool Contains(TOut item)
    {
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<TOut>.Default;
        foreach (var member in Collection)
            if (comparer.Equals(item, ToOuter(member)))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void CopyTo(TOut[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
            array[arrayIndex++] = item;
    }

    public int Count { get { return Collection.Count; } }

    public abstract bool IsReadOnly { get; }

    public abstract bool Remove(TOut item);

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<TOut> Members

    public IEnumerator<TOut> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in Collection)
            yield return ToOuter(item);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    #endregion
}
```

Then an adapted can be constructed for a given `NameValueCollection Data` simply by doing:

```
var adapter = Data.ToDictionaryAdapter();
```

Notes:

- Using the adapter may be be more performant than simply creating a copied dictionary, and should work well with any serializer that fully supports dictionary serialization.

  The adapter might also be useful in using a `NameValueCollection` with any other code that expects an `IDictionary` of some sort - this is the fundamental advantage of the adapter pattern.
- That being said, `JavaScriptSerializer` cannot be used with the adapter because this serializer cannot serialize an arbitrary type implementing `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` that does not also inherit from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.   For details see *[Serializing dictionaries with JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6416950/3744182)*.
- When using `DataContractJsonSerializer`, a `NameValueCollection` can be replaced with an adapter in the serialization graph by using the [data contract surrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates) mechanism.
- When using Json.NET a `NameValueCollection` can be replaced with an adapter using a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) such as the following:

  ```
  public class NameValueJsonConverter<TNameValueCollection> : JsonConverter
      where TNameValueCollection : NameValueCollection, new()
  {
      public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
      {
          return typeof(TNameValueCollection).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
      }

      public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
          if (reader.SkipComments().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
              return null;

          // Reuse the existing NameValueCollection if present
          var collection = (TNameValueCollection)existingValue ?? new TNameValueCollection();
          var dictionaryWrapper = collection.ToDictionaryAdapter();

          serializer.Populate(reader, dictionaryWrapper);

          return collection;
      }

      public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
          var collection = (TNameValueCollection)value;
          var dictionaryWrapper = new NameValueCollectionDictionaryAdapter<TNameValueCollection>(collection);
          serializer.Serialize(writer, dictionaryWrapper);
      }
  }

  public static partial class JsonExtensions
  {
      public static JsonReader SkipComments(this JsonReader reader)
      {
          while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
              ;
          return reader;
      }
  }
  ```

  Which could be used e.g. as follows:

  ```
  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.Indented, new NameValueJsonConverter<NameValueCollection>());
  ```
- `NameValueCollection` supports all of the following

  - A `null` value for a given key;
  - Multiple values for a given key (in which case [`NameValueCollection.Item[String]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.item?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a comma-separated list of values);
  - A single value containing an embedded comma (which cannot be distinguished from the case of multiple values when using `NameValueCollection.Item[String]`).

  Thus the adapter must implement `IDictionary<string, string[]>` rather than `IDictionary<string, string>` and also take care to handle a `null` value array.

Sample fiddle (including some basic unit testing) here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gVPSi7