# How do I convert a querystring to a json string?

Tags: c#, .net, json

Using server-side C#, how can I convert a querystring to a JSON string of keys and values? For example, I want to convert

```
"ID=951357852456&FNAME=Jaime&LNAME=Lopez"
```

to

```
{ "ID":"951357852456" , "FNAME":"Jaime" , "LNAME":"Lopez" }
```

I know how to manually parse and format but, before starting down that road, I thought I'd ask since there might be a library that does it better. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This gives the exactly same json you want

```
var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("ID=951357852456&FNAME=Jaime&LNAME=Lopez");
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                    dict.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => dict[k])
           );
```

Comment: How do you handle arrays?

Comment: The resultset of your answer does not match the OP's requested resultset.

Comment: @Dementic It exactly produces the json string OP wants... (BTW: See the green tick at the left :) )

Comment: Accepted answer dosent mean that it does exactly what was asked. the result of your code would be something like `{ "key": "keyName", "val": "value"}` while the OP asked for `{ "keyName": "
value" }`

Comment: @Dementic `the result of your code would be ......`, **NO**, What is so hard to understand, I just rerun above code and got `{"ID":"951357852456","FNAME":"Jaime","LNAME":"Lopez"}`. Next time please make sure if you don't want to downvote a correct answer.

Comment: I have to agree with @L.B - I ran the code and it works as expected

Comment: @L.B This answer is not precise, it will not work if in the query string there is an array. Maybe it's accepptable but is better if the answer specify this limitation

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET Core you would use `QueryHelpers` instead of `HttpUtility`.  More detail in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29993210/5920517

Answer (score 7):

It also possible to use

```
var collection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(y => y, y => collection[y]));
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use jQuery to do this: [jQuery.Param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Comment: OP is asking for a server side solution.