# What Are Some Options To Convert Url-Encoded Form Data to JSON in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-4.5, forms

I have a web request that is sending the server data that is in the format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  I would like to convert it to `application/json`.

**Example:**

URL-encoded form data:

```
Property1=A&Property2=B&Property3%5B0%5D%5BSubProperty1%5D=a&Property3%5B0%5D%5BSubProperty2%5D=b&Property3%5B1%5D%5BSubProperty1%5D=c&Property3%5B1%5D%5BSubProperty2%5D=d
```

Pretty version:

```
Property1=A
Property2=B
Property3[0][SubProperty1]=a
Property3[0][SubProperty2]=b
Property3[1][SubProperty1]=c
Property3[1][SubProperty2]=d
```

The above data needs to be converted to the following JSON data:

```
{
    Property1: "A",
    Property2: "B",
    Property3: [
        { SubProperty1: "a", SubProperty2: "b" },
        { SubProperty1: "c", SubProperty2: "d" }]
}
```

**Question:**

Are there any free tools that are capable of doing this?  I have not been able to find any myself and if they exist, I'd rather consume them than writing one myself, but if it comes to that, I will.

A C#/.Net solution is preferred.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've written a utility class for parsing query strings and form data. It's available at:

https://gist.github.com/peteroupc/5619864

Example:

```
// Example query string from the question
String test="Property1=A&Property2=B&Property3%5B0%5D%5BSubProperty1%5D=a&Property3%5B0%5D%5BSubProperty2%5D=b&Property3%5B1%5D%5BSubProperty1%5D=c&Property3%5B1%5D%5BSubProperty2%5D=d";
// Convert the query string to a JSON-friendly dictionary
var o=QueryStringHelper.QueryStringToDict(test);
// Convert the dictionary to a JSON string using the JSON.NET
// library <http://json.codeplex.com/>
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
// Output the JSON string to the console
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  I'll look it over.  I couldn't believe that I was the first person out there that needed to do this.  I'm glad that I'm not alone.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work because a bug: you should remove the key in ConvertLists method before add it (315 string): dict.Remove(key); dict.Add(key, newList);

Comment: @AndreyKucher : I believe I fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

The .NET Framework 4.5 includes everything you need to convert url-encoded form data to JSON. In order to do this you have to add a reference to the namespace `System.Web.Extension` in your C# project. After that you can use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class which provides you with everything you need to do the conversion.

**The Code**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("Property1=A&Property2=B&Property3%5B0%5D%5BSubProperty1%5D=a&Property3%5B0%5D%5BSubProperty2%5D=b&Property3%5B1%5D%5BSubProperty1%5D=c&Property3%5B1%5D%5BSubProperty2%5D=d");
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                                                     dict.Keys.Cast<string>()
                                                         .ToDictionary(k => k, k => dict[k]));

            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Output**

```
{
    "Property1":"A",
    "Property2":"B",
    "Property3[0][SubProperty1]":"a",
    "Property3[0][SubProperty2]":"b",
    "Property3[1][SubProperty1]":"c",
    "Property3[1][SubProperty2]":"d"
}
```

*Notice: The output does not contain linebreaks or any formatting*

*Source: [How do I convert a querystring to a json string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428947/how-do-i-convert-a-querystring-to-a-json-string)*

Comment: The output you have included does *not* match my required output.

Comment: @Dan: however, if you decide to write your own this would be a good starting point. it probably would be pretty easy to extend this to match your requirements.

Comment: @Dan: You are right this is not exactly what you wanted. I am sorry for that, but the generated output is valid json.

Comment: @MUG4N I'm not saying it isn't.  I'm simply stating that it does me no good.  Valid JSON is only part of the requirement.  I need valid JSON that correctly represents the data.  I appreciate the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using are ASP.NET Core 1.0+ and JSON.NET you could do:

```
var reader = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormReader(httpRequest.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
Dictionary<string, StringValues> keyValuePairs = await reader.ReadFormAsync();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyValuePairs);
```