# Deserializing the object inside an http post

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am trying to deserialize an Object from a HttpPost method call inside an authorize attribute.I am using ASP.NET Web Api Framework.

Here is my code:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {

      var rezult = DeserializeStream<EvaluationFormDataContract>(actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);

    }

    private T DeserializeStream<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        var rez = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);

        var t = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        return t;
    }
```

When this code gets executed I get this exception when the binaryFormatter tryes to deserialize it:

> The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 73-74-75-64-65-6E-74-41-73-73-69-67-6E-6D-65-6E-74 ...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `BinaryFormatter` to binary deserialize data which was not binary serialized. From data you sent I see that hex code represents a string.

`73-74-75-64-65-6E-74-41-73-73-69-67-6E-6D-65-6E-74` decoded is `studentAssignment`

This leads me to believe you are doing a simple AJAX call and sending JSON data to WebAPI service.

You need to deserialize the stream using JSON.

1. Read request content as string
2. If content is JSON, deserialize it using JSON.NET

---

```
var json = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EvaluationFormDataContract>(json);
```

---

If response is not JSON, but form data you can parse it like a query string.

```
var stringData = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
NameValueCollection data = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(stringData);
string personId = data["personId"];
```

Comment: it does not seem to work the data that I recieve does not seem to be json format.It looks likes this: "personId=4&studentId=10"

Comment: In that case use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) method. See edited answer.

Comment: **Another solution**. I was able to convert Query String `Key` and `Value` to Json Format using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428947/how-do-i-convert-a-querystring-to-a-json-string) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052372/deserialize-http-post-parameters) post. Hope Helps.