# How to receive json post data in a Webhook

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net, kraken-image-optimizer

We are using 3rd party api [kraken.io](https://kraken.io/) to optimize our images.

The results of optimized image is posted in a `Webhook`.

In their api document it states: After the optimization is over Kraken will `POST` a message to the `callback_url` specified in your request in a `JSON` format `application/json`.

I am using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)  to allow remote `webhooks` to send data to my  development machine, using [this](https://www.getdonedone.com/debugging-remote-webhooks-with-ngrok-and-visual-studio/) article.

**Results posted to the Callback URL:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
    "id": "18fede37617a787649c3f60b9f1f280d",
    "success": true,
    "file_name": "header.jpg",
    "original_size": 324520,
    "kraked_size": 165358,
    "saved_bytes": 159162,
    "kraked_url": "http://dl.kraken.io/18/fe/de/37617a787649c3f60b9f1f280d/header.jpg"
}
```

**Class to Map**

```
public class KrakenOptimizedResults
{
public string id { get; set; }
public bool success { get; set; }
public string file_name { get; set; }
public int original_size { get; set; }
public int kraked_size { get; set; }
public int saved_bytes { get; set; }
public string kraked_url { get; set; }
}
```

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OptimizedWebHook()
{

  Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

  string jsonString = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

  KrakenOptimizedResults obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<KrakenOptimizedResults>
  (jsonString);


  return Json(obj);

 }
```

But When I `debug` the received `jsonString` in Html Visualizer it looks like `key` and `value` pairs instead of Json format.

**Received Results not Json Formatted:**

```
file_name=header.jpeg&original_size=118066&kraked_size=102459&saved_bytes=15607
```

I guess the received data `content-type:` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Why i am receiving `key` and `value` pairs instead of Json format ? how can I deserialize Json data in asp.net mvc ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Co-founder of https://kraken.io here.

There is a glaring omission in our documentation which I will fix today. To get JSON back, you need to set a `"json": true` flag in the request. Omitting that flag or setting `"json": false` will return URLEncoded. Example cURL request:

```
curl http://api.kraken.io/v1/upload -X POST --form data='{"auth":{"api_key":"YOUR_KEY", "api_secret":"YOUR_SECRET"}, "wait": true, "lossy": true, "callback_url": "http://requestb.in/wbhi63wb", "json": true}' --form upload=@test.jpg
```

Sorry for the inconvenience :-(

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that, I was not able to set json: true request using your `.Net/C#` SDK, so i extended the  base class and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42247770/2218697) is my solution. Also it would be helpful if method `Optimize` would accept `imageUri`, `callbackUrl` and `optimizeRequest` parameters. Right now it only accepts `imageUri`, `callbackUrl`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to convert Query String `Key` and `Value` pairs to `Json` Format using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428947/how-do-i-convert-a-querystring-to-a-json-string) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052372/deserialize-http-post-parameters) post ,there is some delay to convert form `Dictionary` to `Json`, so If there is better answers, then do post and advice, below is my solution.

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OptimizedWebHook()
{

 Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

 string data = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
 var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(data);
 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k =>
            dict[k]));

 KrakenOptimizedResults obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<KrakenOptimizedResults>
                             (json);

  return Json(obj);

}
```

**Recieving JSON formated optimized results from kraken API.**

As mentioned by @karim79, To get JSON back, you need to set a "json": true flag in the request.

As Kraken `.Net/C#` SDK didn't have option to set "json": true, so i have to extend their base class.

**Extended Base Class:**

```
public class OptimizeRequestBaseExtended : OptimizeRequestBase,
IOptimizeUploadRequest, IRequest
{

    public OptimizeRequestBaseExtended(Uri callbackUrl)
    {
        CallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
    }

   [JsonProperty("callback_url")]
   public Uri CallbackUrl { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("json")]
   public bool JsonFormat { get; set; }

}
```

**Request Kraken API:**

```
var callbackUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:0000/Home/OptimizedWebHook");

OptimizeRequestBaseExtended settings = new OptimizeRequestBaseExtended(callbackUrl);

settings.Lossy = true;
settings.JsonFormat = true;

var response = client.Optimize(image: image, filename: filename, optimizeRequest: settings);
```

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OptimizedWebHook()
{

Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

string jsonString = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();


KrakenOptimizedResults obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KrakenOptimizedResults>
(jsonString);

  return Json(obj);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Create an aspx page. This page must be able to accept HTTP POST request.
Step 2:
Add this code to get HTTP POST data.File: default.aspx.cs
File: default.aspx.cs

```
var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

FileStream ostrm;
StreamWriter writer;
TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;

ostrm = new FileStream(@"C:\logfile4webhook.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
Console.SetOut(writer);
Console.Write(DateTime.Now + " ");
Console.WriteLine(json.ToString() + " ");
Console.SetOut(oldOut);
writer.Close();
ostrm.Close();
```

Step 3:
Create webhook. This code can be linked to a button on click event.File:default.aspx.cs

```
AuthenticationDetails auth = new ApiKeyAuthenticationDetails("your api key");
string listID = "";
listID = "your list id";
List list = new List(auth, listID);
List<string> events = new List<string>();
events.Add("Update");

string postback = list.CreateWebhook(events, "URL", "json");

FileStream ostrm;
StreamWriter writer;
TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;

ostrm = new FileStream(@"C:\logfile4webhook.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
Console.SetOut(writer);
Console.Write(DateTime.Now + " ");
Console.WriteLine(postback + " ");
Console.SetOut(oldOut);
writer.Close();
ostrm.Close();
```

Step 4:
Activate webhook. Copy that webhook id from the text file and past it to the code below.
File:default.aspx.cs

```
AuthenticationDetails auth = new ApiKeyAuthenticationDetails("your api key");
string listID = "";
listID = "your list id";
List list = new List(auth, listID);
list.ActivateWebhook("webhook id");
```

Step 5:
Test weebhook.File: default.aspx.cs

```
AuthenticationDetails auth = new ApiKeyAuthenticationDetails("your api key");
string listID = "";
listID = "your list id";
List list = new List(auth, listID);
string postback = list.TestWebhook("webhook id").ToString();
FileStream ostrm;
StreamWriter writer;
TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;

ostrm = new FileStream(@"C:\logfile4webhook.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
Console.SetOut(writer);
Console.Write(DateTime.Now + " ");
Console.WriteLine(postback + " ");
Console.SetOut(oldOut);
writer.Close();
ostrm.Close();
```

Step 6:
Deserialize body of JSON object. We need to create class structure based on JSON data. I put sample json here and it created required classes

```
public class CustomField
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public List<CustomField> CustomFields { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SignupIPAddress { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public string ListID { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have created your class, append the code from step 2 after

```
var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

to deserialize and parse json.

RootObject myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

```
if (myClass != null)
{
    List<Event> t = myClass.Events;

    string old_email = "", new_email = "";
    old_email = t[0].OldEmailAddress;
    new_email = t[0].EmailAddress;

    //now you can do your logic with old_email and new_email
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question and added `asp.net mvc` its not web form to be clear , and why you posted  big and unrelated answer ?