# Empty message in hi-jacked POST from javascript to C# MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, model-view-controller, post

Im trying to hook myself up to a smaller website im a member in.
It has some kind of chat board based on xml which i parse and do statistics on etc.
Now i want to be able to post short summarys using their own options for posting, handled by JavaScript here (cb is chatboard number):

```
function CB_Post() {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" });
    //alert($("#message").val());
    //$("#fm").serialize()
    $.post("do.aspx?do=add", { message: $("#message").val(), cb: $("#cb").val() }, function (data) {
        if (data == '') {
            document.getElementById("message").value = '';
            FC('message', iMaxChar);
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    }, "text");
```

My implemetaiton so far is:

```
public void PostData(string text)
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data.Add("message", (@text+@"\n"));
    data.Add("cb", "0");
    client.Headers["contentType"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
    var result = client.UploadValues("/cb/do.aspx?do=add", data);            
}
```

This works and the message get sent, but it ends up as a empty string in the chatroom, even if i just send `"hey"`.
Am i missing some kind of formating or encodeing/decoding here?

Answer (score 0):

Well you would think there would be some security that would be preventing you from posting like that so that might be the issue.

However I suspect that do.aspx is expecting JSON data not a NameValueCollection object.

If you take a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003740/how-to-convert-namevaluecollection-to-json-string) it seems the recommended route is to use a `Dictionary<string, string>()` and then serialize it with the `JavaScriptSerializer().serialize`.

Comment: Had the thought about securityissue aswell, but im logged in to the site with the client and when i post it shows up but totally empty.
But will check about doing it true json instead, see if it solves it!