# Translating this to a HTTP POST in C#

Tags: c#, oauth, http-post, yahoo-api

I am currently experimenting with the HTTP request. I have successfully managed to do `get` requests and I have read on doing post request with HTTP request. 
Now I am trying to work with the yahoo API and in order to use the Yahoo api it states that [at](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch01s08.html#)

> The Message Management API can be used to send a message to another
>   Yahoo! Messenger contact. The API is very simple to use, as shown
>   here. Note that the contact that the message is sent to is part of the
>   URI, using the following format:`<server>/v1/message/<network>/<contactID>`

```
POST /v1/message/yahoo/targetYahooId?sid=msgrsessionid  
Host: rcore1.messenger.yahooapis.com  
Authorization: < Standard OAuth credentials >  
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8  
Content-Length: 25  
{  
    "message" : "Hey there"  
}
```

Now I have an OAuth string  which I obtained from get using the HttpWebRequest object.
The string is something like this

```
oauth_token=A%3Dvh....aRg--&oauth_token_secret=bd46a....c9239&oauth_expires_in=3600&oauth_session_handle=ALtT.....3J1N4Zg--&oauth_authorization_expires_in=784964948&xoauth_yahoo_guid=TUSKED5...NCIA
```

**UPDATE**

Now my question are as follows :

1- If I am using WebRequest object in C# what would my URI look like

2- I understand that it requires a JSON type object. How do i even know what OAuth parameters are ?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you'll need to change is the content type:

```
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
```

And of course, the url.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the url on the line with the url in it

you need to change the content-type line

you need to make the payload into a json string then convert it to a byte array (byteArray in the sample)

either assemble the json by hand "{ foo:'bar'}" etc or use json.net

and set the content-length

Comment: and you have to use OAuth to authenticate your user, this link should help http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49

Comment: I have already doen the authentication and have an access token

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's expecting a JSON object for the request body.  Depending on the version of .NET you're using, you can either use a Javascript serializer as shown here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7003815/939080) or JSON.NET (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to convert your form collection into JSON output.

Comment: Thanks i am going to have a look at the JSON.NET

Answer (score 0):

You are asking an open-ended question that would require people to write a bunch of code for you if you want a specific and complete answer.  As others have pointed out, there are several issues that you'd need to deal with:

- The JSON payload, which would be a straightforward matter of putting the JSON string in the request body via the byteArray used in the code sample.
- The content type, which you would need to change as described by jrummell.
- The OAuth credentials, which is a kettle of fish you'll need to read about, understand, and acquire a library for.  Here's a [good place](http://oauth.net/code/) to start looking for a library.