# Deserialize a json-object containing child arrays to custom c#-object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization

Here is my json object:
{"result":"ok","dataType":"2","Data":[["5","1"],["6","2"],["7","3"],["8","4"],["9","5"],["10","6"],["41","7"]]}

I want to deserialize this to a custom c# class that looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class DataRow
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this using the .Net JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: does new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DataRow>(yourJsonObjectString) not work?

Comment: no. fails on the datatype KeyValuePair.

Comment: Can you change that type to Dictionary<string,string>? I remember having issues with trying to serialize dictionary-like collections myself, and I think only string-string dictionary can be automatically [de]serialized using JavaScriptSerializer; your type in that place is similar; you should be able to work with dic<s,s> whereever you're using it (I mean, if deserialization works that way).

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416950/serializing-dictionaries-with-javascriptserializer; it may be that this Json.NET lib can do more than JavaScriptSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the datatype of Data to string[][]. Works like a charm!