# Nested list with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: json, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to produce the following JSON structure with JavaScriptSerializer in Net 3.5:

```
{
    "chart": "pie",
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "Browsers",
            "data": [
                [
                    "Firefox",
                    6
                ],
                [
                    "MSIE",
                    4
                ]
            ],
            "size": "43%"
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue I face is regarding the *data* section. I cannot seem to create a class that serializes into the above structure in *data*.

I have read other posts which kind of touch the subject but the solution always seem to be to use JSON.Net. For instance [Serializing dictionaries with JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416950/serializing-dictionaries-with-javascriptserializer). Although, I primaily want to solve it by using the JavaScriptSerializer or other built-in features in the .Net 3.5 framework.

How do I produce the data section?

***EDIT** The way to solve it with the JavaScriptSerializer is to create an object array for the data property on the object about to be serialized.

Input parameter *data* is "Firefox:6\nMSIE:4\nChrome:7".

public object[] GetData(string data)
{
var dataStrArr = data.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

```
        var dataArr = new object[dataStrArr.Length];

        for (var index = 0; index < dataStrArr.Length; index++)
        {
            var component = dataStrArr[index];
            var componentArr = component.Split(':');
            if (componentArr.Length != 2)
                continue;

            var key = componentArr[0];
            decimal value;

            if (decimal.TryParse(componentArr[1], out value))
            {
                var keyValueArr = new object[2];
                keyValueArr[0] = key;
                keyValueArr[1] = value;

                dataArr[index] = keyValueArr;
            }
        }

        return dataArr;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing dictionaries with JavaScriptSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416950/serializing-dictionaries-with-javascriptserializer)

Comment: The post you linked to has a native .Net solution (overriding the serializer).  Still, much easier to familiarize yourself with JSON.Net ...

Comment: Presumably he's constrained technologically if he's still using .net 3.5, may not have the option of JSON.Net.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like the following class (RootObject) to serialize that:

```
public class Series
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
  public string size { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
  public string chart { get; set; }
  public List<Series> series { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.