# JavaScriptSerializer unexpected output

Tags: c#, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13160227/676406) example to serialize a dictonary like this

```
Dictionary<object, object>
```

What I get is

```
{ "key": "value" }
```

what I need is

```
{ key: "value" }
```

How do I get this output?

Comment: What you need is not a valid json. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: well, yes :) any chance?

Comment: What if your dictionary contains a key like `User Name`? `{User Name: "XmlmXmlmX"}` is garbage.

Comment: problem is, both objects are already strings.

Comment: It seems to be an [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). (*You want to do X, and you think Y is the best way of doing so. Instead of asking about X, you ask about Y.*)

Comment: Maybe you are right. I found another solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong approach - now I use a simple stringbuilder.

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in xSet)
{
  result.AppendFormat("{0}: '{1}',", entry.Key, HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(entry.Value.ToString()));
}
```